# VUEX - Getter da error al hacerlo asíncrono

Tags: vue.js, vuex, async

Quiero enviar un parámetro a un Getter del Store (lo que hace es obtener información de la BBDD)
Cuando indico que el Getter es async, da error.

```
 async getInfoUsuarioBBDD:(state) => (id) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/tareas.json? auth=${state.user.idToken}`)
    const db = await res.json()
    
    const infoUsuario=db
    return infoUsuario
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

```
Error:

SyntaxError: D:\Cursos\VUE\0_proyecto4\src\store\index.js: Unexpected token, expected "(" (223:28)

  221 |     },
  222 |
> 223 |     async getInfoUsuarioBBDD:(state) => (id) => {
      |                             ^
```

Comment: la forma como has definido tu funcion no es valida:
`async getInfoUsuarioBBDD({commit, state}) {}`

Comment: ¿Por qué pusiste los dos puntos ":" en el nombre de la función `getInfoUsuarioBBDD:`?

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza Cuando envío un parámetro a un Getter, si no coloco los dos puntos ":" me salta error. Así me funciona. No me preguntes mas porque no sabría decirte la verdad.

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Pero se supone que los Getters no pueden hacer commit no? porque estas incluyendo un commit al definir el Getter?

Comment: @Inca ¿Pero por qué manejar toda esa lógica dentro del Getter? Ahora hago una respuesta recomendándote otra manera de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo ideal es que el **Getter** devuelva solo el valor de un `state` y nada más.

Mientras que los `actions` son los que se encargan de manejar la lógica, para luego hacer el `commit` que llamará a una función que está dentro de las `mutations`.

A su vez dicha función actualizará el valor del `state`, que es lo que devolverá el **Getter**.

A continuación te muestro un ejemplo de cómo te recomiendo hacerlo en tu caso:

```
export default  {
    state: {
        infoUsuario: null,
    },
    getters: {
        infoUsuario: state => state.infoUsuario
    },
    actions: {
        async getInfoUsuarioBBDD({commit}, id) {
            try {
                const res = await fetch(`<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/tareas.json? auth=${id}`)
                const db = await res.json()
                
                const infoUsuario=db
                commit('SET_INFOUSUARIO', infoUsuario)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_INFOUSUARIO(state, infoUsuario)  {
          state.infoUsuario = infoUsuario    
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Tienes razón, tiene sentido lo que estás haciendo, y cada cosa está para lo que está. Estoy aprendiendo VUE y a veces se me escapan cosas. En cuanto lo pruebe comento.

Comment: Gracias. Lo he hecho como comentas pero en vez de tirar de Getters, he llamado a la accion en el componente para que realice la función al crearse éste:          
 `created(){ this.$store.dispatch("getInfoUsuarioBBDD") }`